# C++, counting the sum of a large number's factorial, like 1!+2!+...+50!, and show it?

Tags: c++

Here is what I need:
I already know how to calculate the factorial of a large number like "50!".

However, I encountered some problems when I use the code to calculate the sum of a series of factorial number like `50!+49!+...+2!+1!`, it seems require more than an array.

I am green, and this program really tortures me, thank you a lot!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
unsigned n=50;
int main()
{
    int a[n][9000]; //bigger
    int digit = 1; 
    int temp;   
    int i, j, k, carry; 



    for ( k=1;k<=n-2;k++)
    {
        a[k][0] = 1;   //
    for ( i=2; i<=n-k+1; i++ )  //
    {  
        for( j=1, carry=0;  j<=digit; j++ )
        {
            temp = a[k][j-1] * i ; 
            temp=temp+ carry;

            a[k][j-1] = temp % 10; 
            carry = temp / 10; 
        }
        while(carry)
        {    
            a[k][++digit-1] = carry % 10; 
            carry = carry / 10; 
        }
    }

    for(j = digit; j >=1;j--)
    {
        cout<<a[k][j-1];
    }
    printf("\n");
    }


    //sum of factorial, a[1][]+a[2][]+...+a[48][]+2!+1!
    int sum[100]; 

    int temp1 = 0;   
    int carry1; 
    int y,u;
    sum[0] = 3;  //2!+1!

    for ( y=0; y<=64; y++ )   //I already know it is 65bits 
    {
        for( u=47, carry1=0;  u>=1; u-- )   
        {
            temp1 = a[u][y]  + sum[y];


            sum[y] = temp1 % 10; 
            carry1 = temp1 / 10; 


        while(carry1)
        {    
            sum[y+1] = carry1 % 10 + sum[y+1]; 
            carry1 = carry1 / 10; 
        }

    }
    }

    for(y = 64; y >=0;y--)
    {
        cout<<sum[y];
    }
    printf("\n");
//    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Based on the lack of code you provided, it appears that you are not adding the calculated large numbers correctly in the arrays.

Comment: sorry, I just put up my code, the final is a sequence of  messy array

Comment: You really ought to avoid `using namespace std` - it is a bad habit to get into, and [can silently change the meaning of your program](/q/1452721) when you're not expecting it.  Get used to using the namespace prefix (`std` is intentionally very short), or importing *just the names you need* into the *smallest reasonable scope*.  You're also missing the include of `<cstdio>` to define `std::printf()` (though I don't recommend mixing iostreams with stdio if you can avoid it).

Comment: What are the "some problems" that you encountered? Give us as much information as possible, please do not expect us all to take your code, compile it and test it to find out.

Comment: So, you are using an array of integers to store a bunch of values from 0 to 9.  That will work, but eventually you will find there are better ways.  The main thing I see that is suspicious is how you handle `digit`  It just doesn't seem like it will work like you think it will.  I would step through a debugger and watch how it changes per iteration.

Comment: Also beware that stack arrays like you have are not preset to 0.  You will need to clear your values or see garbage all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

This is my first time to post a question on stack overflow, and I am so happy to see so many people helping me. Thanks for everybody's help, I have already figured it out(^o^). 
  Actually just as Mr. Dorgan said, I have not preset my array to [0]
  Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
unsigned n=65;
int main()
{
    int a[n][29000]; //尽可能大
    int digit = 1; //输出位数，进位时改变
    int temp;   //阶乘的任一元素与临时结果的某位的乘积结果
    int i, j, k, carry; //carry表示进位



    for ( k=1;k<=n-2;k++)
    {
        a[k][0] = 1;   //将结果先初始化为1
    for ( i=2; i<=n-k+1; i++ )  //开始阶乘，从2开始
    {  //按最基本的乘法运算思想来考虑，将临时结果的每位与阶乘元素相乘
        for( j=1, carry=0;  j<=digit; j++ )
        {
            temp = a[k][j-1] * i ; //相应阶乘中的一项与当前所得临时结果的某位相乘（加上进位）
            temp=temp+ carry;

            a[k][j-1] = temp % 10; //更新临时结果的位上信息
            carry = temp / 10; //是否有进位
        }
        while(carry)
        {    //如果有进位
            a[k][++digit-1] = carry % 10; //新加一位，添加信息。位数增1
            carry = carry / 10; //看还能不能进位
        }
    }
   //显示结果
    for(j = digit; j >=1;j--)
    {
        cout<<a[k][j-1];
    }
    printf("\n");
    }


    //计算阶层和，即a[1][]+a[2][]+...+a[48][]+2+1
    int sum[100]={0}; //尽可能大
    int digit1 = digit; //输出位数，进位时改变
    int temp1 = 0;   //相加后到暂位
    int carry1; //carry1表示进位
    int y,u;
    sum[0] = 9;   //初始化为3!+2!+1!

    for ( y=0; y<=digit-1; y++ )  //从个位开始
    {
        for( u=n-3, carry1=0;  u>=1; u-- )   //从第一个数组开始
        {
            temp1 = a[u][y]  + sum[y];


            sum[y] = temp1 % 10; //更新临时结果的位上信息
            carry1 = temp1 / 10; //是否有进位


        while(carry1)
        {    //如果有进位
            sum[y+1] = carry1 % 10 + sum[y+1]; //新加一位，添加信息。位数增1
            carry1 = carry1 / 10; //看还能不能进位
        }

    }
    }

    for(y = digit1-1; y >=0;y--)
    {
        cout<<"the sum of the factorial to n is"<<sum[y];
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```